# Can I make my listView rows larger?

Tags: android, android-layout, listview

I have a listView that uses a toString to write text to the listView row.
But for what I've seen the listView can only take two rows of text, for example.. I want to write out: "Name: Niklas, Age: 20, Location: Helsingborg, Phonenumber: xxxxxx"
but the listView isnt big enough for all the information to show.

So it only shows this:
"Name: Niklas, Age: 20, 
Location: Helsingborg, Phon .."

My Question:
Can you in some way make the listView rows larger so that it can write out for example three rows of text instead of two? Or do I have to change my listView to another View?

Thanks

Comment: can you post some codes or layouts..

Comment: you can inflate your xml for each row in getView() if you create a class that extends ArrayAdapter.

Comment: You can use a custom listview and inflate row layout accordingly.

Comment: yes, you can. That's actually pretty easy, btw. http://whathaveyoutried.com ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the following links 
[Customized listView](http://www.softwarepassion.com/android-series-custom-listview-items-and-adapters/)
&
[ListView](http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-listview-example/)

The idea is by customizing the lisView by assigning to it its own row layout.

and for the TextView you can assign android:maxLines="" attribute.

Comment: Thanks, after looking into those links I figured out a solution :)

Answer (score 0):

You can define an adapter that extends `BaseAdapter` and overrides the `getView` method.